# shader3 not enabled error in Eve Online Crucible

Tags: 11.10, wine

I'm a complete noob at this, and have been trying everything to run Eve Online within Ubuntu 11.10. I have installed through Winetricks no problem, and have enabled the virtual windows desktop within Winetricks.

My problem is that after the splash screen for Eve, I get an error message telling me that shader 3 is not enabled.  I have an old GEForce 7300LE, but it does support shader 3. I have also tried a few different drivers with no luck. I have tried looking within the NVidia X setting, but can't find anything.

Running Eve on Windows 7 is the only reason I'm still using windows, so any help to run it on Ubuntu would be very appreciated, as I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out something which should be simple.

Comment: Hello, I suggest you take a look at [the Wine AppDB page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=24887), and maybe ask on the WineHQ forums if you can't find a solution. However, [I believe this question (which is specific to your GPU and the quirks of whatever Wine version you're using) is probably too localized for the StackExchange format](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1688/24694) (which is intended to be for documentation as much as support). Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

The following steps were mentioned in a [forum post at EvE Online](http://community.eveonline.com/ingameboard.asp?a=topic&threadID=914238&page=1):

1. You should have wine and msttcorefonts installed.
2. Download the client software for Microsoft Windows
3. Open the file `$HOME/.wine/user.reg` (directory `.wine` in your personal directory. The filename is `user.reg`)

Add the following content:

```
[Software\\Wine\\Direct3D]
"DirectDrawRenderer"="opengl"
"OffscreenRenderingMode"="fbo"
"PixelShaderMode"="enabled"
"VertexShaderMode"="hardware"
```

Now the software should work as expected.